# Rearrange a log file based on keywords

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, jtextarea

Problem:

I work regularly with large log files and I would like to organize some related data that get's written sporadically across the file together to potentially track problems easier.

Example of data written to the log file:

```
1.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-1) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
2.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-16) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
3.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-2) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
4.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-33) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
5.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-1) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
6.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-33) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
7.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-33) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
8.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-2) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
9.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-33) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
10. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-1) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
11. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-6) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
12. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-3) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
13. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-2) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
14. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-14) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
15. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-1) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
```

I have naturally chosen to use (default task-`NUMBER`) as my identifier for grouping related lines together.

I have built my UI and the idea is I would grab an extract from the source log file and then paste this into a `jTextArea` within my Java application, click a button and like magic all the related task numbers (default task-`NUMBER`) will be grouped together. (at first a simple `println` of the grouped data to my IDE of this data would be perfect of course)

I'm currently working on the method that takes all the text pasted into the `jTextArea` and works through it, created string array that I can later expand to find any number of tasks numbers, currently it highlights all the numbers it finds, (not sure if I'm on the correct path though):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class ArrangeLogic {

    public void groupLogFile(JTextArea theLogs) {

        String[] myStringArray = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35"};

        for (int i = 0; i < myStringArray.length - 1; i++) {

            String element = myStringArray[i];
            String nextElement = myStringArray[i + 1];

            String defaultTaskOdd = ("(default task-" + element + ")");
            String defaultTaskEven = ("(default task-" + nextElement + ")");
            System.out.println(defaultTaskOdd);
            System.out.println(defaultTaskEven);

            try {
                Document document = theLogs.getDocument();

                for (int index = 0; index + defaultTaskOdd.length() < document.getLength(); index++) {
                    String match = document.getText(index, defaultTaskOdd.length());

                    if (defaultTaskOdd.equals(match)) {

                        javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter
                                = new javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
                        theLogs.getHighlighter().addHighlight(index, index + defaultTaskOdd.length(),
                                highlightPainter);

                    }
                }

                for (int index = 0; index + defaultTaskEven.length() < document.getLength(); index++) {
                    String match = document.getText(index, defaultTaskEven.length());

                    if (defaultTaskEven.equals(match)) {

                        javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter
                                = new javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
                        theLogs.getHighlighter().addHighlight(index, index + defaultTaskEven.length(),
                                highlightPainter);

                    }
                }

            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I have played around with multiple ideas for the entire day (yes I am a very novice developer) as to how to loop through all lines and re group them together with no luck as yet, so I thought I would ask for some advice. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**(*EDIT*)**

Expected output (LINE NUMBERS DO NOT MATTER):

```
1.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-1) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
5.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-1) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
10. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-1) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
15. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-1) ==>  More stuff written on this line.

2.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-16) ==>  More stuff written on this line.

3.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-2) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
8.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-2) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
13. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-2) ==>  More stuff written on this line.

4.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-33) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
6.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-33) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
7.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-33) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
9.  2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-33) ==>  More stuff written on this line.

11. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-6) ==>  More stuff written on this line.

12. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-3) ==>  More stuff written on this line.

14. 2016-05-05 15:07:54,993 DEBUG (default task-14) ==>  More stuff written on this line.
```

Comment: So you want to get the list of default task numbers ?

Comment: I need the entire line, I will add that to my original post, thanks!

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure to have well understood... You need to get each entire line depending on the default task number ?

Comment: Hi Cukic0d, I have updated my original post with an expected result at the bottom, I think it should make sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not doing it the good way.

Instead of using a loop inside a loop, which is slow, you definatly should use a regex. Then i recommand you to use a scanner to get each line one by one...

Here's a working code explanated how i solved the problem, you may add for yourself the highlighting thing...

```
public static void groupLogFile(JTextArea theLogs) {
    //This is used to get each line one by one
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(theLogs.getText());

    //We are using a HashMap to store the lines in function of the task numbers
    HashMap<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

    //We are now reading each line one by one
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        //With this regex we get at group 2 the task number
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\(default task-(\\d+)\\))");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            //Task number
            int task_number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
            //We get other lines with same task number (if exist)
            List<String> get;
            if(map.containsKey(task_number)){
                get = map.get(task_number);
            } else {
                get = new LinkedList<String>();
            }
            get.add(line);
            //We update the list
            map.put(task_number, get);
        }
    }
    sc.close();

    //Ordering the map by task number
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
          public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
              return o1.compareTo(o2);
          }
    };
    TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> ordered = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>(comparator);
    ordered.putAll(map);

    //Print results
    for(Entry<Integer, List<String>> e : ordered.entrySet()){
        for(String s : e.getValue())
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this, I will try and get back to this problem asap, and report back if I get it right.

Comment: For some reason my IDE is not happy with: 


`HashMap<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();`

Comment: *EDIT* sorry fixed I was importing incorrectly :)  java.awt.List instead of java.util.List

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check for `default task-x` and get the `x`, parse it into a `int` and add the line to `myStringArray[x-1] = myStringArray[x-1] + "\n" + theLine;`
and then remove the first line from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help on the answer Cukic0d! In case anyone wants to see how to print the results to the `JTextArea` instead of `println`:

```
//Clear theLogs (what was pasted into the UI)       
        theLogs.setText("");

//Print results        
        ordered.entrySet().stream().forEach((e) -> {
            e.getValue().stream().map((s) -> {
            //System.out.println(s);
                return s;
            }).forEach((s) -> {
                theLogs.append(s+"\n");
            });
        });
```